# If Joseph was Jesus's adoptive father then did Jesus really have David's blood?

Tags: life-of-jesus, david, genealogy, joseph-husband-of-mary, blood-of-christ

I'm new to this site, but I'm as well searching for answers of several questions I've been facing.

Last Monday, I had a question involving the relationship of Jesus and Joseph.
So far I know, Joseph has been a long-descendant of David. and I believe Jesus was also supposed to have David's blood, because that was the reason why Joseph became his 'mortal father'

But since Maria was pregnant without involving intercourse with Joseph, then Joseph would theoretically have adopted Jesus as his son, breaking the connection of David's blood.

So, to repeat my question again, Is it true that Jesus has the blood from Joseph and finally, also David?

Comment: This is a great question. Unfortunately we can't answer "Is it true" because not all Christians have the same belief. Many evangelicals believe that both Mary and Joseph were descendants of David. As an adoptive father, Joseph's ancestry may still be significant.

Comment: Was Mary not a descendant of David? She provided the physical link while Joseph was not a physical relative of Jesus he as the legal father provided the legal right to David's crown

Comment: Closely related:
http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/43044/how-was-jesus-the-seed-of-david-if-jesus-is-god-who-created-man-adam-and-davi/43058#43058


From Kris

Comment: Your question has several possible answers to it. The following website offers three possible answers: https://gotquestions.org/curse-of-Jeconiah.html. Here is another well constructed answer: thirdmill.org/newfiles/ra_mclaughlin/OT.McLaughlin.Jeconiah.pdf. And another: http://www.whatchristianswanttoknow.com/what-is-the-curse-of-jeconiah-a-bible-study/. Don

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are two lineages in the Gospels.  One - which you have cited - in Matthew, which traces Jesus' ancestry through Joseph, and another in Luke which traces His ancestry through Mary.  Joseph's genealogy, however, also applies to Mary in that she, like he, was of the *house and lineage of David* (Luke 2:4).

John Chrysostom addresses your question directly in a 4th century homily on Matthew:

> “But whence is it manifest that He is of David?” one may say. For if
>   He was not sprung of a man, but from a woman only, and the Virgin hath
>   not her genealogy traced, how shall we know that He was of David’s
>   race? Thus, there are two things inquired; both why His mother’s
>   genealogy is not recited, and wherefore it can be that Joseph is
>   mentioned by them, who hath no part in the birth: since the latter
>   seems to be superfluous, and the former a defect.
>
> Of which then is it necessary to speak first? How the Virgin is of
>   David. How then shall we know that she is of David? Hearken unto God,
>   telling Gabriel to go unto “a virgin betrothed to a man (whose name
>   was Joseph), of the house and lineage of David.” What now wouldest
>   thou have plainer than this, when thou hast heard that the Virgin was
>   of the house and lineage of David?
>
> Hence it is evident that Joseph also was of the same. Yes, for there
>   was a law, which bade that it should not be lawful to take a wife from
>   any other stock, but from the same tribe. And the patriarch Jacob also
>   foretold that He should arise out of the tribe of Judah, saying on
>   this wise: *there shall not fail a ruler out of Judah, nor a governor
>   out of his loins, until He come for whom it is appointed, and He is
>   the expectation of the Gentiles.*” [Genesis 49:10 LXX]
>
> [*Homily II on Matthew*](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf110.iii.v.html)

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Thanks for offering an answer with a supporting quote. This issue is highly debated, so this answer should not be considered definite or definitive. However, it does represent one approach to resolving this issue that has a long history in Christianity.

Comment: Although this does represent one approach to resolving this issue, it is not literally true to say that either of the New Testament genealogies  traces Jesus' ancestry through Mary: both accounts literally trace it back through Joseph. It is only by some convoluted apologetics that we can suppose that Luke's  genealogy was meant to be through Mary.